# Unable to download the sample code for theworldsworststackoverflowclone using Tortoise SVN

Tags: api, tortoisesvn, stackexchange-api

After going through [stackapps](https://stackapps.com/), just tried downloading [theworldsworststackoverflowclone](http://code.google.com/p/theworldsworststackoverflowclone/source/checkout)  with Tortoise SVN.

When I try with Repo-Browser, I get the error:

```
Unrecognized URL scheme for 
hg clone https ://theworldsworststackoverflowclone.googlecode.com/hg/ theworldsworststackoverflowclone
```

or when I right click the local folder and try to check out and then getting the error `file name, volume name or directory name is incorrect`

Comment: `https ://` <- is the whitespace intentional?

Comment: Yes, AS SO was automatically hyperlinking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TortoiseSVN is an SVN client (as the name indicates).
Your project however uses hg (Mercurial), which is a completely different SCM system.

Comment: Nice and concise. It bothers me that something so obvious gets asked here, but still.